# ImportError: cannot import name patterns no django

Tags: python, django

A aplicação no django estava funcionando normalmente até que fui colocar o django-comments, primeiro instalei-o com o setup.py que veio junto, acredito que tenha sido isso que está causando o problema, depois coloquei junto a pasta do projeto e referenciei no settings.py

Então ao rodar a aplicação ele está retornando:

> Na linha 1: "from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url"
>
> O erro: ImportError: cannot import name patterns

Django v1.10

Python v2.7.9

Comment: Como está a fazer os imports?

Comment: Se refere a esse? : from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

Comment: E se tentar: `from django.conf.urls import *`

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
NameError: name 'patterns' is not defined

Comment: Nesse caso ocorreu o mesmo erro que na primeira vez

Comment: Estou a ver documentação e parece estar tudo bem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/urls/

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente quando eu fiz o build do setup ele atualizou a versão do django e a versão que eu estava usando antes deveria ser inferior a 1.8. A partir da versão 1.8 a url fica da seguinte forma:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example